# Google Sign issue without pods iOS

Tags: ios

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/harpreet/Documents/FacebookSDK'
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
>
> objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)